# Indent Lines Up Without Moving

Tags: indentation, cursor-movement

I frequently use the <kbd>></kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> commands to indent several lines at once. Using <kbd>j</kbd>, the lines are indented and my cursor stays at the first line.

When I use <kbd>k</kbd>, the lines are indented, but my cursor gets moved to the first line.

Is there a way to use <kbd>></kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> without the cursor moving up?

#### EDIT

I've found this question
[Why does "Operator" + "Motion" behave inconsistently?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8059/why-does-operator-motion-behave-inconsistently) which explains why this happens. Is there a way to automatically append an <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem you're going to have is that apparently the `>` command doesn't set the jumplist (although I'm not sure why). We can hack it so that it does, but this is a little heavy handed so take it with a grain of salt.

Basically we can do this with a couple of remappings:

```
nnoremap > m'>
nnoremap < m'<
onoremap <expr> k v:operator =~ '>\\|<' ? 'k``' : 'k'
```

The first two lines simply make the `<` and `>` commands set the jump list

- `onoremap` Create a non-recursive "[operator-pending](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#Operator-pending)" mapping
- `<expr>` Allow us to use an expression in the mapping
- `k` Map k
- `v:operator` The command used to enter operator-pening mode. (In our case `>`)
- `=~ '>\\|<'` Only match if the operator is `<` or `>`
- ``` 'k``' : 'k' ``` If the mapping was a `<` or `>`, then jump back one in the jump list after executing `k`. Otherwise just execute `k`.

See [`:help Operator-pending`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#Operator-pending), [`:help :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E), and [`:help v:operator`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Aoperator) for more info.

Comment: Used it yesterday afternoon; works great. You mentioned it being heavy handed, are there are any side effects I should be concerned about?

Comment: I can't think of anything directly. But if there was a plugin that used the jump-list and the `>` feature, it could mess it up as there would be an additional entry in the jump list that the plugin wasn't expecting.